# ssh into pi from Mac over an ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

I'm unable to reach my raspberry pi over an ethernet connection (with a usb dongle).
I turned on internet sharing for ethernet and the command nmap -n -sP 192.168.2.1/24 only returns my mac's adress and `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Raspbian version : 4.19

Comment: Have you [enabled ssh?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)

Comment: If the only connection to the Pi is Ethernet to the Mac, it likely has a link-local address as there's no DHCP.  Use nmap to scan 169.254/16.  Also, please edit your question to include the OS version on the Pi.

Comment: Yes, ssh is enabled, I used ssh through wifi. | Version : 4.19

Comment: Your question doesn't say *anything* about WiFi.  Can you use WiFi to find the Ethernet address of the Pi?  Could you edit your question to tell us a lot more about the configuration of Pi, Mac, and network?  As things stand, anything someone might offer is likely a guess.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Before trying to connect to raspberry pi by SSH, make sure the network connection is Ok. At first, `ping raspberrypi.local` to realize that is there any raspberry pi over the L3 on your network? -- `nmap -n -sP 192.168.2.1/24 ` avoid finding a host address by another host, do it by the router configuration page if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NORMAL**. You can have **EITHER** ICS **OR** `ssh` access, not BOTH.

It is not impossible to have both, but this requires additional software and complex configuration on the laptop, and this is off-topic for this site. NOTHING you can do on the Pi is going to make it work.

NOTE this Question has been asked before e.g. [Why can I connect to my Raspberry Pi when I have internet sharing off, but not when it's on?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74283/why-can-i-connect-to-my-raspberry-pi-when-i-have-internet-sharing-off-but-not-w/74303#74303)

PS there is no such thing as "Raspbian version : 4.19" - see [What Pi Model & OS version is installed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85015/what-pi-model-os-version-is-installed)